# Prononciation du mot « seconde »

Tags: prononciation, étymologie

Pourquoi prononce-t-on « seconde » `sə.ɡɔ̃d` ?

Ma première intuition serait qu'il existe une raison étymologique à cela, mais mis à part cet exemple je ne trouve pas d'autres exemples de **C** prononcés **G**.

Comment: Pour la seconde partie de la question, il y a également le mot « zinc » .

Comment: non on dit "zin-que", mauvais exemple ^^

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Cette situation s'explique en effet par l'origine de *second*, qui est une dérivation du latin *secundus*. Le cas de *second* et de ses dérivés est assez intéressant en ce qu'il ne suit pas la règle habituelle pour les occlusives palato-vélaires ([k] et [g]) à l'intervocalique (entre deux voyelles) et précédant [o] ou [u]. L'évolution normale, décrite par le *Précis de phonétique historique*¹ est la suivante

1. Au IVe siècle, les éventuelles sourdes [k] se sonorisent en [g] par [assimilations double](https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Assimilation_%28phon%C3%A9tique%29#Assimilation_double) avec les voyelles qui l'entourent
2. Le [g] se spirantise en [ɰ] entre le IVe et le Ve siècle
3. Enfin, selon le contexte, le [ɰ] disparait ou passe à [j]

par exemple : *securu* [sekuru] > (IVe) [seguru] > (Ve) [seɰuru] > [seuro] > (VIIIe) > [seɥr] > *sûr*

*Second* s'est manifestement arrêté à 1. Je n'ai pas réussi à trouver d'explication, mais j'ai trouvé un autre exemple : *draco* donne *dragon*, la seule différence est que l'orthographe n'a pas évolué dans le cas de *second*.

Avec cet autre exemple, on peut émettre des hypothèses sauvages : les deux [g] sont suivi de la même nasale [ɔ̃ ], qui pourrait ne pas être étrangère à la bizarrerie. Le seul défaut de cette idée c'est que la nasalisation n'apparait pas en français avant le Xe siècle, donc elle ne peut pas être *directement* responsable, mais je la soupçonne quand même de ne pas être innocente.

---

<sub>1. Noëlle LABORDERIE, Précis de Phonétique Historique, Paris, Nathan Université, Collection 128, n° 59, 1994.</sub>

Answer (score 8):

> Tout commence dans le monde romain avec le verbe « sequere » (suivre),
>   qui donnera « secundus » (suivant). À l’époque, la prononciation de «
>   secundus » comportait le son [k].
>
> Le changement s’opère à la fin du IVe siècle et au début du Ve siècle.
>   On assiste à une « sonorisation des sourdes intervocaliques », [k]
>   devient [g] dans certains cas. Qu’est-ce qu’une sonorisation des
>   sourdes intervocaliques ? Commençons par le plus simple, «
>   intervocalique » signifie « entre deux voyelles » (en terme de son).
>   Le reste n’est pas plus compliqué. Chaque son consonantique est défini
>   par trois paramètres : son lieu d’articulation, son mode
>   d’articulation et son voisement. Dans notre cas, [k] et [g] ne
>   diffèrent que par leur voisement : [k] est une consonne sourde (non
>   voisée) et [g] est une consonne sonore (voisée). En d’autres termes,
>   en prononçant [g] vous faites vibrer vos cordes vocales. Ce n’est pas
>   le cas du son [k]. Cela demande mois d’efforts d’employer le son [g]
>   car les sons vocaliques sont par définition voisés. Ainsi, nous
>   n’avons besoin de cesser de faire vibrer nos cordes vocales pour les
>   refaire vibrer juste après. Dès lors, on ne prononce plus /søkɔ̃/ («
>   sekon ») mais /søgɔ̃/ (« segon »).

[Source](http://www.lapetiteencyclopedie.fr/prononciation-du-mot-second/)

Comment: Mais alors pourquoi juste pour le mot « second » ? Car ni fécond (de *fecundus*), ni faconde (de *facundus*) n'ont un C prononcé G.

Comment: Ecoute bien comment tu prononces *anecdote*.

Comment: *anecdote* ne semble pas être un exemple du changement intervocalique, si j'ai bien compris l'explication. Est-ce qu'il y a d'autres exemples qui suivent le modèle expliqué par Caramel?

Comment: @RomainVALERI Pour *anecdote* ce n'est pas le même phénomène mais une [assimilation rétrograde](https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Assimilation_(phonétique)#Au_sein_d.27un_m.C3.AAme_mot) avec [d]. Quand deux consonnes de la même série avec des voisements différents se suivent, il est courant qu'une s'assourdisse ou se sonorise pour avoir le même voisement que l'autre.

Comment: Si, comme vous l'expliquez, *anecdote* ne participe pas du même mécanisme décrit par Caramel, cela montre que la réponse n'englobe pas tous les cas où (voir question) un **C** est prononcé **G**.

Comment: @RomainVALERI Peut-être, mais la question n'est d'ailleurs pas à propos de tous les cas, mais de *seconde* particulièrement. Par ailleurs, je ne crois pas prononcer *anecdote* avec un G, c'est intéressant...

Answer (score 1):

La différence phonétique entre « *second* », d'un côté, « *fécond* » et « *faconde* » de l'autre, c'est la nature de « *e muet* » de la première syllabe. On peut ne pas le prononcer (et ça devient "zgond"), tandis qu'on ne peut pas ne pas prononcer « *fé* » et « *fa* » dans les deux autres mots.