# Pourquoi est-ce que le c de crocs est muet avec s mais le c de "becs" est prononcé

Tags: prononciation

Il paraît que le *C* est caché par le *S* muet dans "[crocs](https://forvo.com/search/crocs/fr/)" mais pas devant *S* dans [becs](https://forvo.com/search/becs/fr/).

Il doit y avoir une règle d'exceptions autre que prononcer "c, r, f, et l" que je ne connais pas car google translate auto prononce la dernière voyelle dans "break", "infect" et "bled".

Comment: À relier  : https://french.stackexchange.com/q/6601/1893. Prononciation du mot « seconde »

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ***c*** in ***-cs*** can be pronounced or not. There is no real rule I'm aware of but there are two or three times more words where the ***c*** is pronounced.

Here are some words with the ***c*** in ***-cs*** pronounced:

> Alambics, allocs, aqueducs, arcs, bacs, becs, bivouacs, blocs, boucs, caducs, chics, chocs, clics, couacs, ducs, déclics, échecs, grecs, hamacs, lacs, laïcs, parcs, publics, rocs, sacs, secs, trocs, ...

and here are common words with that ending ***c*** mute:

> Accrocs, ajoncs, bancs, blancs, brocs, caoutchoucs, clercs, crocs, entrelacs, escrocs, estomacs, flancs, francs, joncs, marcs, porcs, tabacs, troncs.

Both pronunciations are accepted with:

> Crics

but nowadays, the ***c*** is usually pronounced.

Regional French might pronounce the ending ***c*** in ***porcs*** and other words  like ***caoutchoucs, clercs, tabacs***...

The ending ***c*** in ***zincs*** is expected to be pronounced ***g***.

Both ***c*** and ***s*** are pronounced in ***pacs*** (from the acronym PACS: ***pa***cte **c**ivil de **s**olidarité).

Comment: We see a trend in those words, which is that words with nasal vowels or with the cluster -rc- tend to have kept their c mute, while words that would otherwise end in a single vowel have had the /k/ restored. Part of it is that rC clusters were simplified to just r before liaison appeared as a system, which removes one big way in which final consonants were regained (and diminishes the other, since analogy with other such words will work against spelling pronunciation)

Comment: Which means that "croc" (and prefixed forms like accrocs and escrocs) are a bit unusual. I suspect the reason why they escaped the restoration of their /k/ is that crocs is almost always used in the plural, which also stops the generalisation of its liaison form to other contexts, since it's /z/ and not /k/ that'd have appeared in liaison.

Comment: @Eauquidort That's such a good CV  analysis it should be an answer.